# AngularJS - I want to implement an if-check for an editable field in my HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have built my first AngularJS page and it checks in new visitors and checks out any active visitors on the list.
The app also allows the user to select any active visitor and edit/modify their information.
However my issue is that, during modification, I have no control (as per my limited understanding).

The HTML looks like this:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
       <td></td>
        <td><b>Visitor</b></td>
        <td><b>Title</b></td>
        <td><b>Visitee</b></td>
        <td><b>Arrival</b></td>
        <td><b>Departure</b></td>
        <td><b>Status</b></td>
     </tr>
     <tr data-ng-repeat="user in userList">
        <td><a data-ng-click="selectUser(user)">Select</a></td>
        <td>{{user.Visitor}}</td>
        <td>{{user.Title}}</td>
        <td>{{user.Visitee}}</td>
        <td>{{user.Arrival}}</td>
        <td>{{user.Departure}}</td>
        <td><b>{{user.Status}}</b></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Above is the table structure that shows information about checked in visitors (also shows checked-out visitors with a non-active status field).

There is a "Select" link that allows the user to select any particular visitor and their information gets populated into an editable group of textboxes:

```html
<div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        Visitor: 
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 28px; width: 383px;">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="currentUser.Visitor">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 20px"></div>
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 30px">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        Title: 
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 40px;">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="currentUser.Title">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 20px"></div>
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 30px">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        Visitee: 
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 24px;">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="currentUser.Visitee" >
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 20px"></div>
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 30px">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        Arrival:
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 25px;">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="currentUser.Arrival">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 20px"></div>
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 30px">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        Departure:
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 0px;">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="currentUser.Departure">
    </div>
</div>
```

To checkin and checkout visitors I have the following buttons in html that call their respective functions in my JavaScript code:

```
<div>
    <div style="margin: 2% 0 0 8%; display: inline-block">
        <button data-ng-click="addNew(currentUser)" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Add New Check-in</button>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 2% 0 0 1%; display: inline-block">
        <button data-ng-click="removeItem(currentUser)" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Check-out</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS file looks like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);
app.controller('UserController', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.selectUser = function (user) {
        $scope.currentUser = user;
    }
    $scope.userList = [
       { Visitor: "John Doe1", Title: "Lawyer", Visitee: "James Smith1", Arrival: "01/01/2016 10:45 AM", Departure: "01/01/2016 12:55 PM", Status: "N"},
       { Visitor: "John Doe2", Title: "Contractor Dude", Visitee: "James Smith2", Arrival: now, Departure: tentative_departureTime, Status: "A" },
       { Visitor: "John Doe3", Title: "Attorney", Visitee: "James Smith3", Arrival: now, Departure: tentative_departureTime, Status: "A" },
       { Visitor: "John Doe4", Title: "Maintenance Guy", Visitee: "James Smith4", Arrival: past_checkinTime, Departure: expired_departureTime, Status: "N" }
    ];
    $scope.addNew = function (currentUser) {      
        var now = new Date();
        var departureTime = new Date(now.getTime() + 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        departureTime = departureTime.format("MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm tt");
        $scope.currentUser.Arrival = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a');
        $scope.currentUser.Departure = $filter('date')(departureTime);
        $scope.currentUser.Status = "Active";
        $scope.userList.push(angular.extend({}, currentUser));
        $scope.currentUser = {}; //clear out Employee object
    };
    $scope.removeItem = function (currentUser) {
        if ($scope.userList.indexOf(currentUser) >= 0) {
            var now = new Date();
            now = now.format("MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm tt");
            if ($scope.currentUser.Departure > now) {
                $scope.currentUser.Departure = $filter('date')(now);
            }
            $scope.currentUser.Status = "N";
            $scope.currentUser = {}; // clear out Employee object
        }
        else {
            alert("Please select a visitor before atttempting to check-out.");
        }
    };
});
```

The issue is, lets say I have a `VisitorA`, and the person checked in at 10:00 AM, and is mistakenly marked as checked out at 12:00 PM, the status of their visit is set to "N" (not active) when the current time is 12:05 PM.

I would like to set the checkout time to 01:00 PM (tentative, now that it is in the future). I would like to add a check that will set the status back to "Active" when the departure time is set in the future. I am not sure how to change the status, since I cannot figure out where the "Edit" is taking place.

Comment: How about implementing your `Status` as a calculable property, the one that depends on whether or not they already checked out?

Comment: so I have a check-in button for a new visitor, that takes down their information and sets it to the userList... and then I have a checkout button that accepts all modifications and sets checkout time to current time and sets the status to non-active. In some form, status is calculated.. but I need to be able 'calculate' it on the fly, without the click of the checkout button. As I mentioned above, if checkout time is set to past - status is 'N', if set to future, status is 'A'

Comment: You didn't show the user creating part of your code. The key is using function - preferably defined on `User.prototype` - that checks whether or not user's checkout time is in future and returns true or false; that function will be Status you want to see.

Comment: ok. I sort of understand that, but let me show a bit more of the code...and maybe you can narrow it down for me.

Comment: @raina77ow I added some more of my JS code and HTML code.. can you explain a bit more on how to implement the status check?

Comment: The easiest way would be adding a function into a scope, smth like `$scope.checkUserStatus = function(user) { return user.Departure > Date.now() }`, then using this function in expression `checkUserStatus(user)`.

Comment: May I suggest storing plain DateTime objects in both `Arrival` and `Departure` properties? Not only that allows easier serializing, it also fixes a bug (you compare dates as strings at the moment, so `9/1/2015` is past `10/1/2015`). Filter on output, not in the model.

Comment: yea, but my issue is that the form is editable, without generating any button click events.. all the user has to do is click select... the fields get populated... and then they edit the fields and move on.. no button is clicked, hence no event is generated...

Comment: You don't need to process click if you use function call as interpolated expression; it'll be called on digest anyway.

Comment: and of course, arrival and departure will be date time objects only.. this is me just testing out how angular works.. for fun.

Comment: but where can I call the function? on property change of the textbox 'departure' ?

Comment: You don't call it, just define in on the `$scope`. Then you replace `<td><b>{{user.Status}}</b></td>` with something like `<td><b>{{checkUserStatus(user)}}</b></td>`.

Comment: got it. awesome.  I am sorry I cannot select it as an answer (since you didn't post one). but thank you

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you need a way to update the status of your users as and when it updates in real time.

Using ES6 Javascript you can define a `User` class which has a getter function allowing you to re-calculate the `Status` property on every digest cycle without changing the code in your view.

```js
class User {
    constructor({ Visitor, Title, Visitee, Arrival, Departure } = {}) {
        this.Visitor = Visitor;
        this.Title = Title;
        this.Visitee = Visitee;
        this.Arrival = new Date(Arrival);
        this.Departure = new Date(Departure);
    }
    get Status() {
        return this.Departure > new Date() ? 'A' : 'N';
    }
}
```

Here we can simply call `User.Status` and it will calculate the status on the fly.

Your JS then becomes something like the following (I've kept most of your calculation logic in tact):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);
app.controller('UserController', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {

    class User {
        constructor({ Visitor, Title, Visitee, Arrival, Departure } = {}) {
            this.Visitor = Visitor;
            this.Title = Title;
            this.Visitee = Visitee;
            this.Arrival = new Date(Arrival);
            this.Departure = new Date(Departure);
        }
        get Status() {
            return this.Departure > new Date() ? 'A' : 'N';
        }
    }

    $scope.userList = [
       new User({ Visitor: "John Doe1", Title: "Lawyer", Visitee: "James Smith1", Arrival: "01/01/2016 10:45 AM", Departure: "01/01/2016 12:55 PM" }),
       new User({ Visitor: "John Doe2", Title: "Contractor Dude", Visitee: "James Smith2", Arrival: now, Departure: tentative_departureTime }),
       new User({ Visitor: "John Doe3", Title: "Attorney", Visitee: "James Smith3", Arrival: now, Departure: tentative_departureTime }),
       new User({ Visitor: "John Doe4", Title: "Maintenance Guy", Visitee: "James Smith4", Arrival: past_checkinTime, Departure: expired_departureTime })
    ];

    $scope.addNew = function () {
        // Note: I removed the currentUser argument from the function call since it 
        // was redundant (we can use $scope.currentUser directly)

        var now = new Date();
        var departureTime = new Date(now.getTime() + 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        departureTime = departureTime.format("MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm tt");

        var newUser = new User({
            Arrival: new Date($filter('date')(new Date(), 'MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a')),
            Departure: new Date($filter('date')(departureTime)),
        });
        $scope.userList.push(newUser);
        $scope.currentUser = {}; // clear out Employee object
    };

    $scope.removeItem = function () {
        // Note: I removed the currentUser argument from the function call since it 
        // was redundant (we can use $scope.currentUser directly)

        if ($scope.userList.indexOf($scope.currentUser) >= 0) {
            var now = new Date();
            now = now.format("MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm tt");
            if ($scope.currentUser.Departure > now) {
                $scope.currentUser.Departure = new Date($filter('date')(now));
            }
            $scope.currentUser = {}; // clear out Employee object
        }
        else {
            alert("Please select a visitor before atttempting to check-out.");
        }
    };
});
```

And your HTML remains unchanged!

I agree with the comments that you're best off comparing dates by comparing Javascript Date objects instead of strings, so I've cast the dates in your example to Date objects. For a challenge you could try implementing some setters and getters on the `User` class which allow you to assign a string date value and have it converted into a Date object inside the class.

Read more about ES6 classes here: https://coryrylan.com/blog/javascript-es6-class-syntax.

Note that for support in older browsers, you may need to transpile ES6 using a bundler like Webpack with Babel.